# Exibindo resultados a partir de comparação de datas

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, query, algoritmo-de-busca

Ola!, Tenho uma tabela wp_tblplanos, que contem a data de vigencia inicial do plano e a data de vigencia final, a partir disso, desejo mostrar em uma tabela apenas os resultados que estão dentro do prazo de validade do plano. Tentei o seguinte codigo mas sem resultados:

````
global $wpdb; //global do wordpress

$tabela_planos = $wpdb->prefix . 'tblplanos'; //prefixo para tabela (ignorar)

$tabela_planoempresausu = $wpdb->prefix . 'tblplanosempresausuario';//prefixo para tabela (ignorar)

$atualDate = date('Y-m-d'); //pega a data atual



$PesquisaDatas = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT datVigenciaFinal AS DatF FROM wp_tblplanos"); //pega todas as datas finais do banco

$Indices = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(idPlano) as ids FROM wp_tblplanos"); //conta quantos planos tem no banco

$Qtd = ($Indices[0]->ids); //passa a quantidade de planos para uma variavel

 for($i =0; $i < $Qtd; $i++){ //for para pegar todas as datas finais dos itens nos bancos

  $DataFinal = ($PesquisaDatas[$i]->DatF); //pega a data final


  if(strtotime($DataFinal) > strtotime($atualDate)){ //compara a data final com a atual

      $resultado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT nomePlano, dscPlano, qtdAcessos, qtdBeneficiarios, qtdReponsaveis, vlrUnico, status, vlrMensal FROM wp_tblplanos WHERE datVigenciaFinal > '$DataFinal'"); //aqui tenta realizar aquery para exibir apenas os itens que estão com validade
  }
} ```

Abaixo tenho apenas o foreach para exibir na tabela os itens, nada demais.
````

Comment: Tentou no SQL usando BETWEEN ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código que você poderia ser resumido da seguinte forma:

```php
<?php

global $wpdb;
$tabela_planos = $wpdb->prefix . 'tblplanos';
$tabela_planoempresausu = $wpdb->prefix . 'tblplanosempresausuario';
$resultado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT nomePlano, dscPlano, qtdAcessos, qtdBeneficiarios, qtdReponsaveis, vlrUnico, status, vlrMensal FROM wp_tblplanos WHERE datVigenciaFinal > DATE(NOW())");
```

Na verdade, há vários "problemas" que impedem seu código de funcionar corretamente. Não vou entrar em detalhes, mas você não precisa utilizar o PHP para comparar as datas, e sim fazer isso direto na sua consulta SQL.